# Java Swing combo box selection and link to other combo boxes

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Here is the scenario: I have a table in database with 3 columns (id, name, age). I've created 3 swing comboboxes and a button that sends a "select statement" to the database and fills the comboboxes out with `addItem(...)`.
Now i wanna know how to link comboboxes such that when I select a value from lets say, the second combobox that fetches "name", the appropriate "age" value appears in the third combobox.

My ActionEvent for the button:

```
 jComboBox1.addItem(search.getInt("ID"));
 jComboBox2.addItem(search.getString("NAME"));
 jComboBox3.addItem(search.getString("AGE"));
```

** `search` is the ResultSet I acquire!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement a custom [ComboBoxModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) for such operations.

You can put the logic of your choices inside setSelectedItem method:

```
public class YourComboBoxModel implements ComboBoxModel{
    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem){

    }
    public Object getSelectedItem() {...}
    public Object getElementAt(int index){...} 
    public int getSize() {...}
}
```

and add the desired ComboBoxModel to the relative JComboBox:

```
YourComboBoxModel model = new YourComboBoxModel();
JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
box.setModel(model);
```

Comment: +1 for changing models; `DefaultComboBoxModel` may be sufficient. There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191882).

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261017/how-to-add-different-jcombobox-items-in-a-column-of-a-jtable-in-swing/6261853#6261853, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246005/jcombobox-change-another-jcombobox/6246655#6246655 +1

Comment: Let me try these and get back to ya! After-all still in the process of learning! Tnx