# SwingWorker and JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, swingworker

I have an application that has sheep entries on a `JTable`. Sheep can be made children of other sheep by selecting an id from the `JComboBox` editor of the parent id column in the `JTable`. To do that, the parent id `JComboBox` must scan the ids of other sheep and eliminate some of them as expected and show them together in its `popup`.

This is not a time consuming process; but in my opinion in the future if the sheep count rises, then it may cause the `GUI` become unresponsive. That's why I wanted to use a `SwingWorker` for the scan process. It would be good if it scanS ids in `doInBackground` method and return these ids to `done` method.

So `JComboBox` would show any possible parent ids. Although `doInBackground` method works well in `done` method, when I add a number to `JComboBox`, I guess it makes `popup` become invisible.

Because of this whenever I click the cell of parent ıd `JComboBox` pupup appears and disappears quickly without showing any parent ids. But it must show parent ids. Is there any way to do that?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sheepfarm.tools;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import org.joda.time.Interval;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

/**
 *
 * @author Personal Computer
 */
public class JParentIDCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    private JComboBox jComboBox = new JComboBox();
    private boolean cellEditingStopped = false;

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arrayList.add(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));

        jComboBox = new JComboBox();
        ParentIDCellWorker worker = new ParentIDCellWorker(table, jComboBox, row, value);
        worker.execute();

        jComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    fireEditingStopped();
                }
            }
        });
        jComboBox.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                cellEditingStopped = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                cellEditingStopped = true;
                fireEditingCanceled();

            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            }
        });
        return jComboBox;
    }

    public class ParentIDCellWorker extends SwingWorker<Vector, Vector> {

        private JTable table;
        private JComboBox jComboBox;
        private int row;
        private Object value;

        public ParentIDCellWorker(JTable table, JComboBox jComboBox, int row, Object value) {
            this.table = table;
            this.jComboBox = jComboBox;
            this.row = row;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        protected Vector doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Vector vector = new Vector();
            vector.add(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                try {
                    Interval interval = new Interval(((Date) table.getValueAt(i, 2)).getTime(), new Date().getTime());
                    interval = new Interval(((Date) table.getValueAt(i, 2)).getTime(), ((Date) table.getValueAt(row, 2)).getTime());
                    String gender = table.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
                    if (!vector.contains(table.getValueAt(i, 0)) && gender.equals("Sheep")) {
                        vector.add(table.getValueAt(i, 0));
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException exp) {
                }
            }
            String[] rowsToRemove = getChildren(Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(row, 0).toString()), table).split("-");
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsToRemove.length; i++) {
                vector.removeElement((Object) (Integer.parseInt(rowsToRemove[i])));
            }
            return vector;
        }

        public String getChildren(int id, JTable jTable) {
            String id_map = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < jTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(jTable.getValueAt(i, 1).toString()) == id) {
                    id_map += getChildren(Integer.parseInt(jTable.getValueAt(i, 0).toString()), jTable);
                }
            }
            return id + "-" + id_map;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                for (Object i : get()) {
                    jComboBox.addItem(i);

                }
                jComboBox.setSelectedItem(value);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JParentIDCellEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JParentIDCellEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return cellEditingStopped;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MOD are you meaning this logics in JTable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246005/jcombobox-change-another-jcombobox/6246655#6246655

Comment: kindda. I want efected combobox make calculations in a swing worker to show effected values and when calculation is done show values in its popup. But after calculation is done when i put values into combobox the open popup closes down. So i cant show calculated values in combobox. popup should wait until all values are put into it and usere select one

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but waiting until the user clicks on the popup may be too late. Instead, you could fire up a `SwingWorker` to create a `List<ComboBoxModel>` *before* `getTableCellEditorComponent` gets called, maybe when you construct the parent table's model. That way, your `getTableCellEditorComponent` method could just set the right model for that row. I guess you would have to keep the `List` up to date in the editor, but that seems much easier.